# Return NULL values when using min()

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns images by a specific month (the min). The query works fine, except that the min never return NULL values, and i need the MIN to include NULL values. I understand that MIN does not return null values, that's why i've tried COALESCE, IFNULL, ISNULL and even LEAST, with no success..

Here's the query

```
SELECT i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month
FROM image i
JOIN (
    SELECT i.published_date_year year, MIN(i.published_date_month) month
    FROM image i
    WHERE i.is_listed = 1
    GROUP BY i.published_date_year
) t1 ON t1.year = i.published_date_year AND t1.month = i.published_date_month
WHERE i.published_date_year = 1967 AND i.is_listed = 1
ORDER BY i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month, i.published_date_day, i.image_id DESC
```

Notice

```
MIN(i.published_date_month)
```

I want to be able to return null values. Looks like MIN is not the correct function, so what is the correct function or formula?

Comment: You can return  0 for null

Comment: tried  MIN(IFNULL(i.published_date_month, 0)) month but then no images  are returned because there is no such month that equals 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that COALESCE, IFNULL, ISNULL and maybe LEAST worked just fine. The problem is that you use the result afterwards to join with `i.published_date_month` and obviously nothing equals `NULL`:

```
... ON t1.year = i.published_date_year AND t1.month = i.published_date_month
```

You can add an expression built around `OR t1.month IS NULL` to your expression or simply pick an invalid month as dummy value:

```
... ON t1.year = i.published_date_year
    AND COALESCE(t1.month, 0) = COALESCE(i.published_date_month, 0)
```

Still, I hardly see how this can make sense. Does `image` store data without months?

Comment: the `OR t1.month IS NULL`  did not work, i got no results. And yes, most of the time, i have no clue what the day and month and even the year of the image is.

Comment: that is exactly my problem. i've added `MIN(IFNULL(i.published_date_month, 0)) month` and changed the afterwards formula to `AND COALESCE(t1.month, 0) = COALESCE(i.published_date_month, 0)` and all works fine!! Now, i just need to study the formula, make sure i understand all those COALESCE 's.. thanks!!

Comment: Please note the `OR t1.month IS NULL` part is not full code you can just append—I was just calling your attention towards `IS NULL` (vs `=`). You'd need to ensure that both involved columns are null at the same time.

Comment: As about `COALESCE()`, it's rather similar to other functions you mention. I tend to use it because it's a SQL standard function that works in all DBMS I work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ifnull and a case

```
   SELECT 
      i.published_date_year year
   , case MIN(ifnull(i.published_date_month, 0))
     when 0 then null
     else   MIN(ifnull(i.published_date_month, 0)) 
     end month
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for `NULL` separately with a `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(i.published_date_month IS NULL) = 0 
          THEN MIN(i.published_date_month)
       END
```

This returns `NULL` when there is at least one `NULL` found in `i.published_date_month`.